# find_by NoMethodError in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following line of code,

```
user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
```

That is throwing an error

```
NoMethodError in SessionsController#create

undefined method `find_by' for #<Class:0x007f67187ef730>

Rails.root: /home/dj/portfolio/sample_app
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

In other parts of the code I have successfully used `find_by_email` with no error. What could be causing this method to not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use `User.find(email: "mail@example.com")` or `User.find_by_email("mail@example.com")`. `User.find_by` does not exist.

Comment: Hmm, I am actually following a tutorial (railstutorial.org) and in both revisions of the tutorial it uses the same method.I changed it to find_by_email and altered the code and it works. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I believe it's because of the release of new rails 4. If I'm not mistaken, rails 4 has deprecated all the find_by* methods and is now using a find_by method that takes in arguments as you saw in the example/guide. Looks like you were accidentally looking at rails 4 tutorial. this was confusing me earlier today..

Comment: For the record: [find_by documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by)